# Creating a component in React.js: is "React.createClass" still usable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Some months ago I began to study react.js, then I abandoned it. Today I have begun to study React again. Reading the official documentation I find that the syntax of how to create a component has changed. In the past I learned to create a component in this way:

```
reactComponentElement = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
      return <h1>Title</h1>;
   }
})
```

so, using React.createClass.

Today I see in the docs that the creation of a component can be achieved with a function

```
function reactComponentElement(){
   return <h1>Title</h1>;
}
```

or with a class

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

So, can I still use React.createClass?

Answer (score 3):

If I am coding in ES 5.1 I am still using the syntax:

```
var ComponentName = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <some JSX />
        )
    }
})
```

However, when I am writing ES 6 syntax, I use the `extends` declaration if I want a 'smart' or class based component (one that displays and messes with data):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ComponentName extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <some JSX />
        )
    }
}
```

But not every component needs that and I can just as well declare functional components (I call these 'dumb' components because I simply use those to get something on the screen) in ES 6:

```
const ComponentName = () => {
    return (
        <some JSX />
    )
}
```

I noticed in the React documentation that there is a mismatch between ES5 and ES 6 syntax (as in some pages are still in ES 5, others are in ES 6). You can find the ES6 syntax here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 0):

In function

```
function reactComponentElement(){
   return <h1>Title</h1>;
}
```

you are not creating react component wit all it's meaning - you just return some JSX. Classes are available only in ES6 and higher, so if you code in ES5, you still have to use React.createClass();
[React.Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: Have you read the question? "So, is it React.createClass no more used?" My answer- "if you code in ES5, you still have to use React.createClass()". Is something wrong or you cannot understand my answer?

Comment: I think it's a good reply :)
I just wait for other possible replies before I mark it with the green check

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to only use function components (a function from props to html) + [hooks](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

They are simple to reason with, future proof, and hooks make code super simple and less verbose to reuse